# Which alcohol will most easily react with HCl to form an alkyl halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Which alcohol will most easily react with HCl to form an alkyl halide?

A. Primary alcohol

B. Secondary alcohol

C. Tertiary alcohol

D. All alcohols react equally to form alkyl halides

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tertiary alcohols have greater reactivity with hydrogen halides than secondary alcohols, which in turn have comparatively more reactivity than primary alcohols. For tertiary alcohols, the reaction proceeds by an SN1 mechanism which prefers a more substituted alcohol. 
Therefore answer is C

Comment: Add explanations, please.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).